# Animations not restarting when moving between view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a number of animations that start automatically when my root view controller is loaded. These animations are included in `viewDidLoad`. When i navigate to my next view controller and return to the root view controller, all the animations have stopped. The same behaviour occurs when i press the "home" button and then return to the the view.

I'm sure i'm missing something very basic here but would appreciate any help. Thanks.

**EDIT 1**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self beeBobbing];
    //animate the butterfly oscillating
    [self butterflyOscillate];

}

-(void) beeBobbing
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction ) animations:^{
        CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(215.0, 380.0);
        imgBee.center = bottomPoint;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}
```

**EDIT 2**: This type of animation seems to restart when changing between views:

```
-(void) animateClouds
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:30.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        CGPoint leftScreenCenter = CGPointMake(-420.0, 119.0);
        imgClouds.center = leftScreenCenter;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        CGPoint rightScreenCenter = CGPointMake(1450.0, 119.0);
        imgClouds.center = rightScreenCenter;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:40.0f delay:0 options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) animations:^{
            CGPoint leftScreenCenter = CGPointMake(-420.0, 119.0);
            imgClouds.center = leftScreenCenter;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

    }];

}
```

Comment: What type of animation you are doing (core animation,uiview animation.opengl , etc) and on what event?

Comment: You will have to do the same in viewDiDAppear also to animate as itgets called on switching between views.call [self beeBobbing];

in viewDidAppear

Comment: i don't understand the logic of your beeBobbing animation... you set a position to a fixed point, always the same... so why do you need to REPEAT it???

Comment: @meronix I'm not sure i understand but i'll try to explain what i've done. `imgBee` already has a position of `(215.0, 410.0)`. It's moved to `bottomPoint` over the space of a second and back again and repeated infinitely. If your question is why do i create `bottomPoint` inside the animation then yes, that's my mistake - the animation still won't restart though when changing views

Comment: i'd use a NSTimer for that, it may resolve all your problems

Comment: @meronix I've edited the post above to include an example of one of the animations that works correctly when switching between views. I can't understand why the `beeBobbing` method won't work. Are you suggesting using an `NSTimer` to time the animation? How does this interact with `animateWithDuration`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think if you give all animation in `viewWillAppear:` then its work fine...
thats it...
:)

Answer (score 3):

viewDidLoad is just called when you first load your controller the first time, if then you navigate to other viewControllers with some push or you change tab, you don't pass in viewDidLoad...

try to start your animations in the method - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: I've put my animation methods in `viewWillAppear` but not all of them seem to be working when navigating between views. The `beeBobbing` animation in the post above is not functioning.

Comment: can you try to use it in viewDidAppear...?

Comment: This gives the same result, but also with a big delay before animations begin the first time

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the animations in `viewWillAppear:`. `viewDidLoad` is called once when the controller is initialized and the view is loaded either from a nib or created in the `-loadView` method (if overridden) and won't be called again until the controller is destroyed and created again. The methods that fire when you navigate back and forward are `viewWillAppear:` `viewDidAppear` `viewWillDisappear:`.

Comment: I've put my animation methods in `viewWillAppear` but not all of them seem to be working when navigating between views. The `beeBobbing` animation in the post above is not functioning.

Comment: viewWillAppear: fires before the view is shown, so your animation may finish before the view becomes visible. try putting some delay on the animation, or put it in viewDidAppear... You have to make out the best timing...

Comment: The animations i'm using are looped so they aren't finishing before they appear. Also, when i put the animations in `viewDidAppear` i get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed is that you need to set position of the view that you want to animate in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`

```
imgClouds.frame = set frame here and this is most important
[self beeBobbing];
```